# How to say "You got this" in Italian?

Tags: translation

***[You’ve got this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/you-you-ve-got-this)*** is  meant to be said to someone else, and to be encouraging.

Comment: *Ce la puoi fare*, oppure, *dai che ce la fai*!!!

Comment: Welcome to ItalianSE!!!

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for the shortest phrasing for an art piece I'm making. Would any of these work? 

Ci sono arrivato
L'hai capito
Ce La Fai
Hai questo

Answer (score 6):

An idiomatic translation could be

> Dai che ce la fai!

This can be used only as an exhortation (i.e. when you encourage someone to finish a task, e.g. in the last kilometer of a marathon). If you want it to be a description, for example as an answer to someone asking your opinion, you could simply say

> Ce la fai.

or

> Ce la puoi fare.